# @ApiMethod with @Nullable parameter, get-client-lib generates checkNotNull

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine

I have an API call defined as

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getID", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public SimpleResponse getID(@Nullable @Named("ses") String ses)
```

After running endpoints.cmd get-client-lib to generate the android client java files, the constructor for getID gets defined as

```
protected GetSessionID(java.lang.String ses) {
      this.ses = com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(ses, "Required parameter ses must be specified.");
    }
```

My client app isn't able to send a null value for "ses" due to the checkNotNull. Am I wrong to assume that I can send a null value coinciding with a nullable parameter?

Comment: This may be a good one to report on the public issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues) as the behavior seems to contradict what is specified in the docs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#nullable).